# Jquery popover not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop, tooltip

It is a small Json Based small application in which user can drag and drop iteam from one column to another. Also items has their individual descriptions which are hide on load, it is getting true only when you click on Item List.
please check with below issue

I have implement Jquery-ui Tooltip (http://jsfiddle.net/bh4ctmuj/164/) on click of  List Item in Json DOM element,  Drag and drop functionality.  But i'm not able to figure out why Jquery-ui tooltip is not working.

throwing error as follows

```
"message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function",
"filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
"lineno": 147,
"colno": 32
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'jSon.json',
                    data: '',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        //console.log(data);

                        $.each(data.hotels, function (i, hotel) {
                            $('.hotels').append("<li class='hotel' title='" + hotel.description + "'>" + hotel.name + "</li>");
                        });
                        $('.hotels').append('<div></div>');

                        $.each(data.location, function (i, place) {
                            $('.locations').append("<li class='place'>" + place.name + "</li>");
                        });
                        $('.locations').append('<div></div>');
                    }
                });
                $('li.hotels').tooltip({
                    position: { my: 'center bottom', at: 'center top-10' },
                    tooltipClass: "myclass",
                    disabled: true,
                    close: function (event, ui) { $(this).tooltip('disable'); }
                });

                $('li.hotels').on('click', function () {
                    alert();
                    $(this).tooltip('enable').tooltip('open');
                });
            })

      $(function () {
                $("#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3").sortable({
                    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
                }).disableSelection();
            });
```

```css
ul.hotels, ul.Locations, ul.drop-container {
        list-style-type: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .hotels li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        background: #6eb0e5;
    }

    li.hotel {
        background: #c7dff6;
        border:#4c85b2 solid 1px;
        color:#4c85b2;
    }
    li.place{
     background: #daedd5;
     border:#53a464 solid 1px;
     color:#53a464;
    }

    span{
     display:none;
    }

    .Locations li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        background: #80cb9a;
    }

    .drop-container li:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        background: #80cb9a;
    }


    .float-left {
        float: left;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: left;
    }

    #sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3 {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
      
        min-height: 20px;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 0 0 0;
        float: left;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

        #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
            margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
            
        }

        #sortable1 li, #sortable3 li {
            margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 1.2em;
         
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Assi</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />





    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="">
            <div class="float-left">

                <ul class="hotels connectedSortable" id="sortable1">
                    <li>Hotels</li>
                </ul>

            </div>


            <div class="float-left">
                <ul class="Locations connectedSortable" id="sortable1">
                    <li>Locations</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="float-left">
                <ul class="drop-container connectedSortable" id="sortable3" type="A">
                    <li>Hotels & Locations</li>
                    <li class="hotel">Hotel 1</li>
                    <li class="place">Loction 1</li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicate include, remove one of the `jquery-ui` library includes :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: NO both are required.

Comment: What you mean? the same library included two times that will create a conflict... and the both are including `tooltip`..

Comment: if i remove any one of them it is showing error in console
check with link
http://proittechnology.com/dev/assign/

Comment: i have removed one library

Comment: @harshadpatil You should only include jQuery UI once. You also need to make sure jQuery is loaded first, THEN jQuery UI.

Comment: @Tieson I did same. but my issues  Jquery-ui Tooltip (http://jsfiddle.net/bh4ctmuj/164/) on click of List Item in Json DOM element, not working